# Where can I see what powers I can unlock when?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

I have tried searching if someone asked it before, but I fail to find it.

Before the update, when you clicked your reputation you went to a page where you could see all the power you could unlock. It had a % on it to show how far you where to a certain power.

Now clicking your reputation takes you to a history of your reputation. Is the old unlockable page still around and how can I get to it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges

This is accessible through the Help Center:

[image: Help Center Button]

[image: Privileges in the Help Center]

Comment: strange, mine says activity and logout.

Comment: @Andy Only on Meta